# Socket.io 1.0 emitting events internally

Tags: node.js, socket.io

### Socket 0.9 and Earlier

Previously in Socket.io 0.9 there was an exposed method under [namespace.$emit(...)](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/0.9/lib/namespace.js#L42) which allowed you to use the NodeJS EventEmitter functionality to bind on events.

```
io.of('namespace').on(...)
```

This could be used to emit events within the same socket.io without needing to do any sort of external client or other method.

### Socket.io 1.0

It appears in Socket.io 1.0 this was removed in favor of a [private variable](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/namespace.js#L38).

Is there an official method or best way to send and receive socket.io events within the same application without needing to use socket.io-client and connect to the server?

### Workaround

I've worked around the issue for now by creating my own callback registration, but I would much rather use socket.io to internally listen on it's own events and utilize it's namespaces.

```
socketIO.register = function(event, callback){
    socketIO.registeredEvents = socketIO.registeredEvents || {};
    socketIO.registeredEvents[event] = socketIO.registeredEvents[event] || [];
    socketIO.registeredEvents[event].push(callback);
};
socketIO.emitInternal = function(event, eventData){
    if(!socketIO.registeredEvents[event] || socketIO.registeredEvents[event].length === 0) return;
    socketIO.registeredEvents[event].forEach(function(callback){
        callback(eventData);
    });
};
```